# How to block incoming call

Tags: android, filter, block, phone-call

How to block an incoming call on Android? I have searched the questions and only been able to block the call but the phone rings for a second. Is it possible to block the call without letting user know that it has been, I mean without any ring or waking of the display screen. Thanks

There is an app that lets you do this. its available on the play store
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsBlocker